# Psubscribe redis command on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

On my rails app I've launched a worker to subscribe to multiple channels based on a pattern. For that I used psubscribe as the following:

```
REDIS.psubscribe("*:expire") do |on|
  on.message do |event, data|
    puts 'Acquired'
  end
end
```

On a specific controller I'm calling:

```
REDIS.publish("key:expire", "testing")
```

This works perfectly if I use subscribe with the string "key:expire". However psubscribe does not work. Anyone had problems using psubscribe on Rails.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After long experiments I've found this solution,
you should use "pmessage" instead of "message" when you're doing psubscribe. Also pmessage receives three parameters instead of two in subscribe.

```
REDIS.psubscribe("*:expire") do |on|
 on.pmessage do |event, channel, data|
   puts 'Acquired'
 end
end
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
REDIS.psubscribe('__key*@*__:expired')
```

This way it works for me. See here [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/notifications)